# How to dispose memory in three.js r154

Tags: performance, memory, three.js

when rendering multiple objects memory not released and mouse movent is very
slow. when perform copy paste object. system  running very slow.

we dispose all arrays,geometry,material and texture but memory are not released.

What is solution !!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Regarding your question, JavaScript will hold a resource in memory as long as there is a reference to it in an active scope. Once you post your disposal code, we can potentially determine if anything is holding the data. Once the data has been properly orphaned, then it becomes eligible for garbage collection.